# How to get the extended pdf version

Tags: pdf, version

In the toolbar of adobe reader, in File->Properties->Description->PDF Version, you can only find the "big" version of pdf, but not the version extensions introduced by recent Adobe software.

For example, if I have two pdf files, one is pdf 1.7.3, the other is pdf 1.7.5. In the file properties, I can only find pdf version 1.7.

Does anybody know how to check the pdf version in details?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PDF versions are 2 numbers only, X.Y. The existing PDF versions are 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7.
 Starting with 1.7 Adobe added version extensions. The version extension information (a dictionary) is stored in the /Extension key in document catalog. The version extension dictionary has the /ExtensionLevel entry which can give you the 3rd number in your versions above.
I assume you consider PDF 1.7 Extension level 3 as 1.7.3.

Comment: Just one more question: where I can find the extension information?

Comment: Adobe Acrobat displays this information in file properties dialog (Ctrl-D or File menu > Properties), the Description tab, Advanced section, PDF Version field. With other tools I do not know.